# Estimating the best solution of an equation in one variable

Tags: python, linear-programming, estimation

`[v0, v1, v2, .....] = 3(3222.56) + 0.1339[0,1,2,3,...... 1023](a+b+c)`

`n=[1,2,3,............ 1023]`
`v= [v0, v1, v2, ..... v1023]`
This is the equation that I need to solve in which size of `v` and `n-whole no. matrix` is `1024*1` and is `a, b & c` are unknown, and we have to find the best solution out of all the values of `v` and `n`.

I need to solve this in `python`, and I already tried hand on the method of least squares but the equation didn't transform into its form, so kindly help out.

Comment: Matrix X is the [a, b, c], the variables. `v` is an array of values`[v1, v2, v3................ v1023]`, which we have already and n is the matrix getting multiplied to [a, b, c], `n=[0, 1, 2, 3, .............................1023]`

Comment: Please improve clarity and readability of your question @MohammadAreebAkhter

Comment: I suspect this problem is not correctly stated. (1) a,b, and c are indistinguishable. (2) looks like least squares (3) but then "find the best solution out of all values of v and n" does not make much sense. I would suggest starting to write down the mathematical model in more detail. Maybe you can sit down with a colleague or teacher to help you with this.